# When HTML elements cannot call functions defined in external JS

Tags: javascript, html

I got this solved out, but seeking to understand why the first and second tries didn't work:

I basically got a HTML element attached with an event (myFunction()): `echo '<button class="btn remove-btn" onclick="myFunction(' . $row["id"] . ')">X</button>';`

I wanted to define the `myFunction()` function is defined in external JS file, but it didn't work at first and second try:

1. First attempt with custom.js - failed

> myFunction is not defined

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    //some jQuery code for other purposes
    
    //the myFunction is defined here
    function myFunction(id) {
        window.open("remove_cat.php?id=" + id, "width=200,height=100");
}
    
})
```

2. Second attempt with custom.js - failed

> myFunction is not defined

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    //some jQuery code for other purposes
    }
    

//the myFunction is defined here
function myFunction(id) {
    window.open("remove_cat.php?id=" + id, "width=200,height=100");
}
```

3. Moving the function definition to the PHP file itself - Worked
4. Creating another `myfunction.js` file - Worked:

```js
function myFunction(id) {
        window.open("remove_cat.php?id=" + id, "width=200,height=100");
}
```

Comment: Have you link your external js file to your html page?

Answer (score 0):

The first one failed because you don't declare a function within the `$(document).ready` to make it callable. $(document).ready calls all functions within it when the page is ready to be safely manipulated.  You do not need to declare functions within `$(document).ready`.  You also have a syntax error (missing a semi-colon at the end).
https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

The second one failed because you have a syntax error.  You need to fix it with the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //some jQuery code for other purposes
    });
```

Comment: missing the semicolon is not a syntax error, it is a recommendation but is not required.

Comment: The main reason the first one fails is because of variable scope. Declaring the function inside `$(document.ready()` makes it local to that function, but functions called from HTML attributes have to be in the global scope.

Comment: Thanks guys! Now I see why the first code fails but I still haven't really figured out what's wrong with the second code. Isn't it the same with moving that function declaration to a separate JS file like the 4th attempt (which worked)?